# Understanding simple recursive function

Tags: python

I don't understand how the following code have an output of 3?

I get that     n %= 5 output 4 which go to the else statement.
so it should be return     rec(4-1) + rec(4-2)
so how does this output 3?

```
def rec(n):
    n %= 5
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return rec(n-1) + rec(n-2)
print(rec(9))
```

output: 3

Comment: "This make rec(3) + rec(2) which is both less than 1" - uh, what? What do you think is less than 1? Neither 3 nor 2 is less than (or equal to) 1, so you can't just stop there.

Comment: Walk through it step by step on paper... or [Visualize execution](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know what recursive function was and confused on how remainder works.
I keep going after``` rec(3) + rec(2)```
```rec(3)``` would become ```rec(2) + rec(1)```
and ```rec(2)``` would be ```rec(1) + rec(0) ```
reuse the function again for ```rec(2)``` because of the outcome of ```rec(3)```

and finally I have``` ((rec(1) + rec(0)) + rec(1)) + (rec(1) + rec(0))```
which equal to 3 because return n when n<=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this kind of problem is to track the recursive calls:

```
rec(9):
  n = 4 # ( 9 % 5)
  return (rec(3) + rec(2)) # rec(n-1) + rec(n-2)

rec(3):
  n = 3
  return rec(2) + rec(1) # rec(n-1) + rec(n-2)

rec(2):
  n = 2
  return rec(1) + rec(0)

rec(0) = 0

rec(1) = 1

rec(2) = 1

rec(3) = 2
```

therefore `rec(9) = 3`

Answer (score 0):

When I run a few tests on the code, the value you input re-defines n to be 3. This executes the else statement which produces the values 2 for rec(3-1) and 1 for rec(3-2). This has the function return the value 2+1 which is where your 3 output is coming from.